# Find centre and radius of circle given position vector of moving particle.

Tags: vectors, circles

A particle $P$ is moving such that at time $t$ its position vector is
\begin{align}
\mathbf{r}(t)=a\Big((2+\sin(3\omega t))\mathbf{i}-(1-\cos(3\omega t))\mathbf{j}\Big),
\end{align}
where $a$ and $\omega $ are constants.

How do you show this moves in a circle? And how do you find it's centre and radius?

Comment: Hint: take $x=a(2+sin(3ωt)$ and $y=-a(1-cos(3ωt)$

Comment: Hint2: you need $(x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2 $ to be a constant, what must be the values of $ x_1 $ and $ y_1 $?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest 
to type mathematical expressions in your posts 
using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020).